# Calculate average from a series with fixed interval

Tags: matlab, mean

I have a time series with `12` data points x `n` sessions. All the values are in one column.

I would like to average over all sessions so that I would get 1 series with only `12` data points. For instance, I could have:

```
[a1 a2 ... a12 b1 b2 ... b12 c1 c2 ... c12]
```

The outcome should be `[mean(a1, b1, c1) mean (a2, b2, c2)... mean(a12, b12, c12)]`

Could anyone help me do this efficiently in Matlab?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of elements in your original series will always be a multiple of 12, so you can use `reshape()` to yield an 12 x n matrix.  From there using `mean()` is straightforward to get the vector that you want.

```
nSessions = 20; % Choose an integer to test number of sessions
TestData = 1:12; % Dummy data - col 1 = 1, col 2 = 2...to check that our reshaping is correct
data = repmat(TestData, 1, nSessions); % Test data of the expected form
reshapeData = reshape(data, 12, []); % Reshape into an 12 x N matrix;
meanData = mean(reshapeData, 2);  % Take mean along rows to yield desired answer
```

Comment: Thank you, Staus. For some reason when I ran this, it gave me the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions error". When I applied to my data, I got another error: Subscripts indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. I got the logics of this but not sure what went wrong here.

Comment: Do a `clear all` before you run my code to make sure it's not something from old variables causing problems.  If that doesn't do it run each line individually and figure out which one gives the error.

Comment: You were right. It was indeed something that I had been working with interfered with the code. Thank you so much. That works wonderfully.